# Content Encoding Error on new IIS 7 server with PHP

Tags: php, iis, compression, encoding, cakephp

I recently moved a PHP (Cake framework) development site from an IIS 6 (x86) server to an IIS 7 server (x64). The content is all the same and the URL rewriting works, but on the attempt to display the first page I get this error:

```
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.
```

Firefox identifies this as

```
Content Encoding Error The page you are trying to view cannot be 
shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
```

The PHP pages are using Gzip `(ob_start("ob_gzhandler"))` but commenting out this line doesn't do anything. The IIS install is nearly a clean install and I've never set up any compression options, is there any setting in IIS or code error that would cause this? The same exact code works on the IIS 6 server. I've heard of this being caused by trailing white space in PHP but if that were the case shouldn't the IIS 6 server have the same issue?

The browsers I tried were Firefox 5, the latest Chrome and IE8, however it's not a browser side issue.